# Hooking into jquery animate function

Tags: jquery

when animate function will decrease the height & width of div then any other function can run parallelly. suppose i want to fadeout my div before it's height & width becomes 0 zero.
basically i want that when my div's height & width decrease 50% then i want to make it fadeout. is it possible?

animate has callback but callback will be invoke when animate complete..which i don't want.
here is sample my animate code

```
$('#my-id').animate({width: 0, height: 0}, 1000);
```

if possible then please tell me the solution with sample code. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a [step function](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#step) to `animate()`, and it will be called for each step in the animation. In this function, you can set the element's opacity appropriately as soon as its height reaches half of its original value:

```
$("#my-id").animate({
    width: 0,
    height: 0
}, {
    duration: 1000,
    step: function(now, fx) {
        if (fx.prop == "height") {
            var threshold = fx.start / 2;
            if (now < threshold) {
                $(fx.elem).css("opacity", now / threshold);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This should behave as you expect and run the two effects in parallel. In passing, note that the resulting fading animation will be more fluid if the element is taller than it's wide. If your element is wider than it's tall, you might want to monitor its `width` property instead of its `height`.

Comment: how to detect what is the current height & width from step function? few line is not clear to me like .... what it does...var threshold = fx.start / 2;
what kind of information now can give? please discuss in detail and positively tell me...how to detect what is the current height & width from step function?

Comment: As explained in the page I linked to, the step function receives two arguments: `now`, which is the current value of the animated property, and `fx`, which contains the animated element (`fx.elem`), the animated property (`fx.prop`), and the start and end values of the animated property (`fx.start` and `fx.end`). The `threshold` variable is assigned half the starting height of the element and is used both to determine if we crossed the 50% threshold and to compute the opacity value.

Comment: i use and test ur code. it is working fine but the way i want to fadeout my div which is not happening. here i update my code. please have look into the url.. http://jsfiddle.net/Sj4eG/12/ . i set the threshold hard coded like 150 because my div height & width is 300X300 px. so i want that when animate decrease the size of my div close to 150 px then i want to fadeout smoothly the div. i tried the samething using ur code...but i am not getting the effect i want after using ur code. so please check ur code.

Comment: just go to this site http://demos.kendoui.com/web/window/index.html . from where just close the window and u can see that window is getting fadeout before it's height & width becomes zero. how to achieve it...plzz guide. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can run 2 animations one after the other:

```
$('#my-id').animate({width: 50%, height: 50%}, 1000).fadeOut("slow");
```

Comment: ur code has bug. 50% is not right. i think u did not test it.

Answer (score 0):

Animate your params to the 50%, then do `fadeOut` and then continue animation (but actually last animation I thing not needed at all, because it's already invisible).

```
$('#my-id').animate({width: 50, height: 50}, 1000, function() {
   $(this).fadeOut('fast', function() { 
       $(this).animate({width: 0, height: 0}, 1000);
   });
});
```

or without last animation:

```
$('#my-id').animate({width: 50, height: 50}, 1000, function() {
   $(this).fadeOut('fast', function() { 
       $(this).css({width: 0, height: 0});
   });
});
```

Comment: i can not give width hard code like 50. rather i have to detect that when height & width decrease 50% then i have to make it fadeout. so tell me how to do it.

Comment: just go to this site http://demos.kendoui.com/web/window/index.html . from where just close the window and u can see that window is getting fadeout before it's height & width becomes zero. how to achieve it...plzz guide. thanks

Comment: In this case 2 animations works in parallel. You don't need to use any callbacks, just invoke 2 animations one by one (not in callback). Here is the sample: http://jsfiddle.net/pefTW/

Comment: thanks...so u means to say that animate and fadein() function both works parallel.